# curl and wget works for some sites and fails for others

Tags: linux, curl

I have a linux machine from which when i try to curl google it works but when i try to curl some other sites it fails.

```
ABC /home/cool> curl https://www.google.com
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(func
```

Same for other sites also. So i guess my outbound firewall configuration are fine else it would have been failing for all. Also site which i am curl-ing has no whitelisting of ips etc. But  when i   try for other

```
ABC /home/cool> curl https://failing-site.com
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

wget has also same result ...it can resolve the ip but fails to connect.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: can you provide one of these websites that you've tried and haven't worked for you. Also, just because you can resolve the IP address, it doesn't mean you can get response from the server or you're connected for that matter. it only means that the domain name you're referring to is mapped to an IP address. there might be no server on that IP endpoint to respond; or an HTTP server.

Comment: so i tried similar things from other similar linux box and everything works fine from that box curl and wget so there is server corresponding to that ip.
I am sorry but can't help u much with site-name ...

Comment: try `telnet failing-site.com 443` .. what do you get?

Comment: @Ram it just hangs and then
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx: Connection timed out

Comment: It has nothing to do with curl. Your machine is unable to reach `failing-site.com` on port `443` (or `80`). Things to troubleshoot are your network devices (firewalls/routers) and if you are running IPtables on local machine, start there.

Comment: @Ram i stopped firewall, still have same  issue ....any other suggestion

Comment: moreover other sites i am able to hit so shouldn't be firewall issue

Comment: @pkm sorry mate. out of ideas. I think it all comes down to some silly detail you are overlooking, like you might be trying https when it is running just http? vice versa? Did you try pinging failing-site.com?

Comment: @Ram doesn't matter thanks for help,also tried ping it works and has tried http and https both